# convert string to float in linux loadable kernel module using c-language

Tags: c, linux-kernel, floating-point, kernel-module

I'm developing a LKM in C using eclipse cdt for Linux kernel ver 2.6.38(ubuntu)

I have the following structure data type in my LKM with following members

```
struct example {
signed short mem1;
float mem2;
float mem3;
};
```

I have a /proc file through which I want to give input to this LKM and initialise this structure's data members.

My /proc file buffer looks like this:

```
static char procfs_buffer[1024];
```

and will have a string value like this
`"-123,-77.123456,-66.123456,"`

I want to initialise the structure members like,

`mem1 with -123;` `mem2 with -77.123456;` `mem3 with -66.123456;`

I'm able to seperate above string as :

```
string str1[5] with value 123 ;
string str2[5] with value 77 ;
string str3[8] with value 123456 ;
string str4[5] with value 66 ;
string str5[8] with value 123456
```

and using `simple_strtol()` I converted these strings to long numbers.

I was able to convert `str1` to `long` and then cast it to signed short and  multiplied result by negative sign, and assigned it to `mem1`

**Now, my problem is the float members. As kernel doesnot allow floating point operations, I'm stuck with this one. I'm not able to do the calculation using integers. When i tried I'm not able to insert module after compiling. I know FP is not possible in kernel.**

Is there anyother wayout.? its very urgent..please somebody help me...

Somebody suggested me to use binary representation of floating point numbers in proc file buffer instead of representing as character buffer. But, my proc file is a char buffer, and furthermore, again how do I convert from string to float, I will be facing the same problem again.

Comment: "The kernel does not allow floating point operations" -- really???

Comment: There is this -msoft -float & -mhard -float options..But I dont know how to use this -msoft -float option to emulate FP operations. I'm using Makefile, may be somebody can tell me how to specify this compilation option in the Makefile

Comment: Hm, well, it's possible that you do have those restrictions, though I wonder how you can be expected to use a structure that contains `float`s if you're not allowed to use floating point operations. I always thought that if you don't have a hardware FPU, the compiler will emulate floating point operations, but perhaps this doesn't apply to free-standing programs.

Answer (score 3):

I needed a string to floating point number conversion algorithm that does not use standard C library, so I've written one. It also does not use floating point math. I've described the algorithm and published the code in [my article](http://krashan.ppa.pl/articles/stringtofloat/). The code has a good parser handling all conventions of scientific notation. It also supports proper generation of +/- infinity and +/- zero, according to IEEE754.

Answer (score 1):

One of the main reason the Kernel doesn't allow FPU operations is because of the additional overhead it would add to context switching. Whenever the processor switches from user<->kernel space a set of registers needs to be swapped. Adding the FPU context would be exceptionally inefficient.

However the kernel does actually implement some floating point code itself. It does this for FPU emulation (providing an emulated FPU for user-space). I suspect it might be possible to patch something up to use the emulation routines to get FPU primitives that don't impact on user-space.

However I think you really need to consider if you need floating point arithmetic inside your kernel module? Could some sort of fixed point solution not solve your problem?